# Pending image node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, phaser-framework

I'm having problem with my phaser view, it seems that the image is always pending
i'm trying to get the image from a static folder in the node js server, this is a screen and the code above can you help me please ?

```js
module.exports.GetImage = function(req,res){
 var img_name = req.params.name;
 res.sendFile(path.resolve("./kidAvatar/"+img_name));
}
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95vSp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using path.resolve() takes arguments in path segments, so you don't need the forward slashes in yours. Try using `path.resolve("/kidAvatar", img_name)`

Also see the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Comment: I change it but it doesn't work now even in localhost ... please other suggestion ?